# Rails 5 message app wan't show chatroom messages unless reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm doing tutorial on message_me app but messages I write and hit `enter`wan't show up on index chatroom page unless I reload the page. I've tried with two browsers Firefox and Chromium and both consoles show me the error in  same file and same line: app/assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.coffee: 
`}, $('#message-container').append(data.mod_message), scroll_bottom());`

ReferenceError: data is not define

And here is my app: https://github.com/Citizen1/message_me

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` in the `received` method of `app/assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.coffee` to make sure you're getting data back?

Comment: I've tried and I'm getting data back. But I see also in my rails server this message at the end of transaction:```No template found for MessagesController#create, rendering head :no_content``` . And then if reload page I can see the message

Comment: Do you have `remote: true` on your form?

Comment: Yes I have in app/views/chatroom/index.html.erb, you can see it in my github repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `chatroom.coffee` file. You have to indent the lines under `received: (data)`:

```
received: (data) ->
  $('#message-container').append data.mod_message
  scroll_bottom()
```

[CoffeeScript](https://coffeescript.org/) has strict [indenting](https://coffeescript.org/#language) guidelines.

Comment: It's working now, I can't believe solution was so banal!